# inDither = true Android

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

Could someone explain what is really happening when setting **inDither = true** in the context of configarating a bitmap in Android?

At Developer.Android one can read about the static variable

```
Config.RGB_565
```

*This configuration can produce slight visual artifacts depending on the configuration of the source. For instance, without dithering, the result might show a greenish tint. To get better results dithering should be applied*

I had this problem until I followed this recommendation, that is:

```
options.inPreferredConfig = Config.RGB_565;
options.inDither = true;
```

So my question: how do one understand inDither in Android. Its one thing to know **when** to use a syntax ... another to fully understand it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have You read http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/12/08/bitmap-quality-banding-and-dithering/ ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you are running low on the number of colors supported , then moving from one color to other (gradient) will cause bands to appear (less steps in between).

[Dithering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dither) reduces this by placing random noise in color steps. With dither, we can use a noise of available colors to give an illusion of unavailable colors:

[image]

`RGB_565` has low precision (2 bytes) than `ARGB_8888` (4 bytes). Due to low color range, `RGB_565` bitmaps can show banding and low color range. Hence, dither flag is use to improve perceived image, and give an illusion of more colors.