# How to get the correct image for the ListView using Custom SimpleCursorAdapter with MediaStore?

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, mediastore

i have project right now like a youtube thumbnails style,
i create already the custom simplecursoradapter
that display image, title, artist, duration of a video from sdcard using mediastore,

my problem is the only the image is error but the title, artist, duration is already in order, what i notice is the image is not getting the right thumbnail from the video,
the title, artist, duration is the only that dont have problem,

i have a 10 video at my sd card, 
the list view display the title, artist, duration in a right order
but the image is somthing not corect and i i drag the list the image changes also,
i want to get also the right image for the video per list order..

this is my code

```
public class TABThisWeek extends ListActivity {

    Cursor videoCursor;
    int videoColumnIndex;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Uri sourceUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION };

        String orderBy = MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE;

        // CREATE CURSOR THAT WILL HOLD ALL VALUE
        videoCursor = getContentResolver().query(sourceUri, projection, null,
                null, orderBy);

        // THE DESIRED COLUMNS TO BE BOUND
        String[] from = { MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION};

        // THE XML DEFINED VIEWS WHICH THE DATA WILL BE BOUND TO
        int[] to = { R.id.list_Title, R.id.list_Artist, R.id.list_Duration };

        /*
         * CREATE THE ADAPTER USING THE CURSOR POINTING TO THE DESIRED DATA AS
         * WELL AS THE LAYOUT INFORMATION
         */
        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.list_row_items, videoCursor, from, to);

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        setListViewAttributes(); // set listview divider color etc
    }

    /* get ListActivity's own ListView and sets the divider color */
    private void setListViewAttributes() {

        ListView lvTab = getListView();
        ColorDrawable cd = new ColorDrawable(this.getResources().getColor(
                R.color.color_divider_black));
        lvTab.setDivider(cd);
        lvTab.isScrollbarFadingEnabled();
        lvTab.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
        lvTab.setFadingEdgeLength(25);
        lvTab.setDividerHeight(1);
    }

    /* Custom Adapter for TabThisWeek */
    public class MyCustomAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

        private Cursor c;
        private int layout;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private MyViewHolder holder;
        BitmapFactory.Options options;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            // this.context = context;
            this.c = c;
            this.layout = layout;
            this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

            holder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();

            if (holder == null) {
                holder = new MyViewHolder();

                holder.titleHolder = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_Title);
                holder.artistHolder = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_Artist);
                holder.durationHolder = (TextView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_Duration);
                holder.imageHolder = (ImageView) view
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_Image);

                /* getting the index because auto loop */
                holder.titleIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
                holder.artistIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST);
                holder.durationIndex = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
                holder.imageIndex = cursor.getInt(cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));

                view.setTag(holder);
            }

            /* set the Title but if null set to default from resources */
            try {
                holder.titleHolder.setText(cursor.getString(holder.titleIndex));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.titleHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_title));
            }

            /* set the artist but if null set to default from resources */
            try {
                holder.artistHolder.setText(cursor
                        .getString(holder.artistIndex)); // temp
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.artistHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_artist));
            }

            /* set the time duration if null set to default */
            try {
                holder.durationHolder.setText(cursor
                        .getString(holder.durationIndex)); // temp
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.durationHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_duration));
            }

            try {
                options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inDither = false;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;

                holder.bitmapVidThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails
                        .getThumbnail(context.getContentResolver(),
                                holder.imageIndex,
                                MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);

                holder.imageHolder.setImageBitmap(holder.bitmapVidThumb);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                holder.imageHolder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources()
                        .getDrawable(R.drawable.default_img));
            }

            /* set default value if title is null */
            if (holder.titleHolder.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                holder.titleHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_title));
            }

            /* set default value if artist is null */
            if (holder.artistHolder.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                holder.artistHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_artist));
            }

            /* to get and check if time is below 0 for exception */
            holder.durationTemp = Long.parseLong(holder.durationHolder
                    .getText().toString());
            if (holder.durationTemp <= 0) {
                holder.durationHolder.setText(getResources().getString(
                        R.string.default_text_duration));
            }
               }

        /* my nested view holder class */
        class MyViewHolder {
            Bitmap bitmapVidThumb;

            ImageView imageHolder;
            TextView titleHolder;
            TextView artistHolder;
            TextView durationHolder;

            int imageIndex;
            int titleIndex;
            int artistIndex;
            int durationIndex;
            long durationTemp;

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Do not use `SimpleCursorAdapter`.You should use `SimpleCursorAdapter` only, by when you don't need any customization. Use the `BaseAdapter` Check out http://gypsynight.wordpress.com/2012/02/17/how-to-show-all-video-file-stored-in-your-sd-card-in-a-listview/

Comment: because if want to use the holder i need to custom it? because if i dont use the custom simple cursor adapter my listview performance will slow, my problem is how to get the right image for my imageview for the listview using the MediaStore from all the video in my SDCARD, how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

When the adapter recycles rows, you're getting a value for holder.imageIndex that belonged to a different row.  You should move the cursor operations outside of the if(holder == null) section, so they don't get recycled from another row.

Here's how I would edit your bindView function:

```
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        holder = (MyViewHolder) view.getTag();

        if (holder == null) {
            holder = new MyViewHolder();

            holder.titleHolder = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Title);
            holder.artistHolder = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Artist);
            holder.durationHolder = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Duration);
            holder.imageHolder = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.list_Image);

            view.setTag(holder);
        }

        /* getting the index because auto loop */
        holder.titleIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE);
        holder.artistIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.ARTIST);
        holder.durationIndex = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DURATION);
        holder.imageIndex = cursor.getInt(cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));


        //... the rest of the bindView function
```

Comment: Can I suggest you visit Vogella.com. There is a tutorial there that exactly covers the point made by tjav. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @ jtav - so all holder operation should i put it outside the (holder == null)? can u edit my custom simple cursor adapter to the right one that you stated, is it ok? thank you so much!

Comment: @ Theo - i visited that site already but i cant find ways to solve my problem, but thanks for the info!

Comment: @ jtav - can i ask a follow up question about BitmapFactory.Options ".inDither = false;" what does it do?

how can i get the image thumbnail exactly from the start of the video screen? because there is a video that it gets its video thumbnail from after 11 secs frame i think and all 9 videos video thumbnail frame img from 1sec.. can i custom the image of the frame that i get from it using only min API lv8?

Comment: For just displaying thumbnails, you probably don't need to adjust the .inDither option, but here's a description: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17639206/2995580)

Comment: The original video probably had a thumbnail that was made at the 11 secs frame.  You can try this, but it might give you the same thumbnail:
`    Bitmap thumb = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(path,
        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
`
You can go into the video if you want to get the first frame:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823763/2995580)